# Sap abap save change log functionality of orders

Tags: abap

I have created a table which saves the changes that are made in an order in IW32.

I do that in the smod->IWO10009

```
SELECT SINGLE AUFNR VAPLZ
    FROM CAUFV
    INTO ZPM_Custom_table
    WHERE AUFNR = CAUFVD_IMP-AUFNR
    and vaplz <> CAUFVD_IMP-vaplz.

  IF SY-SUBRC = 0.
    ZPM_CAUFD-Z_DATE =  sy-datum.
    ZPM_CAUFD-Z_USER = SY-UNAME.
    ZPM_CAUFD-Z_WC_NEW = CAUFVD_IMP-VAPLZ.
    ZPM_CAUFD-Z_WC_OLD = CAUFV-VAPLZ.
    MODIFY ZPM_Custom_table.
  ENDIF.
```

Problem is that the `CAUFV-VAPLZ` is empty and I need a way to insert into `ZPM_Custom_table` the old value of `VAPLZ`.

I also need to the same for the `ARBPL` which is in the table `AFVGD`,both the old and the new values.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `Problem is that the CAUFV-VAPLZ is empty` why it is empty? Does the select run successfully?

Comment: @Suncatcher yes it does & IDK why its empty,to get the I do this::`SELECT SINGLE ARBPL
  FROM CRHD AS C
  INNER JOIN VIAUF_AFVC AS V
  ON C~OBJID = V~ARBID
  WHERE V~AUFNR = @CAUFVD_IMP-AUFNR
  INTO @ZPM_Custom_table.`  however this takes too much time

Comment: Try to change to `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF ZPM_Custom_table` in the first select

Comment: @Suncatcher the problem is that the custom table is created in se11 and has only 6 fields in total,r u sure it will solve the problem?

Comment: @Suncatcher UPDATE just tried it doesnt work

Comment: Then VAPLZ is empty in DB, why it seems strange for you?

Comment: @Suncatcher because VAPLZ is not empty

Answer (score 1):

`CAUFV-VAPLZ` is empty because you don't fill it anywhere. It's neither defined nor supplied anywhere within your snippet.

Comment: and how should I solve this?please give an answer,not an explanation that would be way more welcome

Comment: I see that you select into `ZPM_Custom_table` work area but read from `CAUFV` structure. That is the reason. Florian is right: CAUFV is never filled.

Comment: @Suncatcher I already fixed that problem sorry for not updating you,but now I insert them into lt_table declare as type caufv and then pass the variable from lt_table now in order to insert the VAPLZ it inserts into my table a value of 2100 & I dont know why it doesnt select the right value wich is NDT